# Android - Is it possible to promote to beta through Google Developer API?

Tags: android, google-api

Currently if I want to promote my Android app from Alpha to Beta, I do it in Google Developer Console.
I am trying to automate this process using the C# client of Google APIs. Is it possible? If so, I'd love to see a code sample.
Thanks!

Comment: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en hope this help

Comment: Thank you, but I read this already.
A more relevant link is this: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/tracks
But it doesn't mention anything about promoting to beta. I tried to use the Patch() function, but I doesn't work in the case of promoting to beta.
What I need is either a code sample or for someone to tell me that what I'm trying to do is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer myself, based on the answer I got here: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-publisher-api/issues/20#issuecomment-107923343

Something like this works for me:

```
        var service = new AndroidPublisherService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential
        });

        // Insert new edit
        var edit = new AppEdit()
        {
            ExpiryTimeSeconds = ToEpochTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(30)).ToString()
        };
        edit = service.Edits.Insert(edit, packageName).Execute();

        // Fetching the Alpha track and clearing the version code from it
        var tracks = service.Edits.Tracks.List(packageName, edit.Id).Execute().Tracks;
        var alphaTrack = tracks.Single(track => track.TrackValue.Equals(EditsResource.TestersResource.GetRequest.TrackEnum.Alpha.ToString(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
        var versionCode = alphaTrack.VersionCodes.Single();
        alphaTrack.VersionCodes.Clear();
        service.Edits.Tracks.Patch(alphaTrack, packageName, edit.Id, EditsResource.TracksResource.PatchRequest.TrackEnum.Alpha).Execute();

        // Updating a Beta track with the same version code as in the Alpha track
        var betaTrack = new Track {TrackValue = "beta", VersionCodes = new [] { versionCode }};
        service.Edits.Tracks.Update(betaTrack, packageName, edit.Id, EditsResource.TracksResource.UpdateRequest.TrackEnum.Beta).Execute();

        // Commit the edit
        service.Edits.Commit(packageName, edit.Id).Execute();
```